# Asp.net dynamic structure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, element

I want to create a website where it is possible to add dynamically "X" dropdown-lists (or other elements)

These dropdown-lists should be shown on the website and furthermore there should be an other element be shown, that depends on the dropdown-list (for example: if the user chooses option "A" there is a checkbox, if the user chooses "B" there is a input field)

Is this possible with ASP.NET (Vb.net)? (I know that this works with PHP)

thanks in advance

Comment: you can do all this even without any ASP.NET ... just plain javascript (better using jQuery just for the sake of simplicity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with Asp.Net.
But my advice to you is to do it with javascript framework such jquery or 
ExtJs without request to server.

Comment: `ExtJs` just for this is kind'a overkill don't you agree? :)

Comment: I agree it's overkill , jquery better

Comment: greate, do you have some links for me :) ?